# AttributeError: set_model Error (Keras callbacks)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback

I am fitting a model using Keras and passed the callbacks list to the model fit, but encountered the following error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, 
    ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, Callback

    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(f'model{i}.h5', save_best_only=True,
                                 save_weights_only = True,
                                 monitor='val_loss',
                                verbose = 1)
    
    lr_reducer = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss", 
                                    patience=3, 
                                    min_lr=1e-6)
    my_callbacks = [checkpoint, lr_reducer]
    
    history = model.fit(
        train_generator,
        validation_data = valid_generator,
        epochs=10,
        verbose=1,
        callbacks= my_callbacks)
```

The error is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-0538428c86d8> in <module>
     75         epochs=10,
     76         verbose=1,
---> 77         callbacks= my_callbacks)
     78 
     79 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1073             verbose=verbose,
   1074             epochs=epochs,
-> 1075             steps=data_handler.inferred_steps)
   1076 
   1077       self.stop_training = False

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in __init__(self, callbacks, add_history, add_progbar, model, **params)
    229 
    230     if model:
--> 231       self.set_model(model)
    232     if params:
    233       self.set_params(params)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py in set_model(self, model)
    284       model.history = self._history
    285     for callback in self.callbacks:
--> 286       callback.set_model(model)
    287 
    288   def _call_batch_hook(self, mode, hook, batch, logs=None):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastcore/basics.py in __getattr__(self, k)
    387             attr = getattr(self,self._default,None)
    388             if attr is not None: return getattr(attr,k)
--> 389         raise AttributeError(k)
    390     def __dir__(self): return custom_dir(self,self._dir())
    391 #     def __getstate__(self): return self.__dict__

AttributeError: set_model
```

It only says 'AttributeError: set_model' and I don't understand what's causing the error.

Comment: Would you please add your imports to the question? It may be conflicts of your imports. And additionally please say what do you mean of ``{i}`` in ``model{i}.h5``?

Comment: I edited the question with imports. And `{i}` ,because I am doing cross validation. When I commented out `lr_reducer = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss", patience=3, min_lr=1e-6)` and gave callbacks as  `callbacks=[checkpoint]` it worked, but I don't know why including `lr_reducer` throws an error.

Comment: Have you checked that all other objects such as layers, model and ... comes from ``tensorflow.keras`` and not from ``keras``?

Comment: Yes, I did, but still, the error is there.

Comment: Can you share complete code to replicate your issue?so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sometimes if you write in the list all required callbacks it accepts but sometimes you should assign it to another variable then write it like this.**
history = model.fit(
train_generator,
validation_data = valid_generator,
epochs=10,
verbose=1,
callbacks= [my_callbacks])
**may your model.fit() will work.**